# Formulate a conjecture about when the set $\{f(n) : n \in \mathbb{Z} \text{ and } f(n) \text{ is prime}\}$ is infinte.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

**Q:**
Let $f(x)=x^2 + ax + b$ $\in Z[x]$ be a quadratic polynomial with integer coefficients, for example, $f(x)=x^2 +x+6$. Formulate a conjecture about when the set $$\{f(n) : n \in \mathbb{Z} \text{ and } f(n) \text{ is prime}\}$$ is infinite. Give numerical evidence that supports your conjecture.

I have no idea...
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I think this is an open problem.  See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/208614/existence-of-polynomials-of-degree-geq-2-which-represent-infinitely-many-prim.

Comment: Note that $x^2+x+6$ is always even (if $x$ is an integer).

Answer (score 1):

I think this holds if $f(x) = x$, because $\{f(n) = n $ and $n$ is a prime number $\}$ is a infinite set

And may be $f(x) = x² + ax + b$ such that $f$ doesn't has integers roots

So there's not exist some descomposition $f(x) = (x-r)(x-s)$ with $s,t \in \mathbb{Z}$

Then I think it can has inifinite prime numbers

Please correct me if I'm wrong, I hope it helps